# Passing value of JSON data to Free Pascal variable

Tags: json, lazarus, freepascal, delphi

I'm trying to put together a small program in Free Pascal that gets current exchange rates from [Fixer.io](http://fixer.io/) in JSON format and uses them to do simple currency conversion.
I've got as far as the following, which downloads the exchange rate from GBP to Polish złoty and prints it to the screen.

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses fphttpclient, fpjson, jsonparser;

Var
  S : String;
  J: TJSONData;
  initialAmount, endAmount, rate: real;

begin
  With TFPHttpClient.Create(Nil) do
    try
      S:=Get('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=GBP');
    finally
      Free;
    end;
    J:= GetJSON(S);
    writeln ('Current exchange rate of GBP to Polish złoty: ',J.FindPath('rates.PLN').AsFloat:2:2);
end.
```

What I'm struggling to do is pass the value of that exchange rate to a variable that I can use for currency conversion.

Something along the lines of this:

```
rate := J.FindPath('rates.PLN').AsFloat:2:2;
writeln;
write ('Enter initial amount in GBP £');
readln (initialAmount);
endAmount := initialAmount * rate;
writeln (endAmount);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed code looks fine, apart from two problems.

1. I would expect the compiler to report the first problem: remove the `:2:2`. IIRC, that notation is reserved for the `WriteLn` statement.
2. The second problem should be obvious if you read the code: on the last line, you're printing the rate instead of the end amount.

Comment: Ah, I've amended the last line of the program to display the end amount instead of the rate. The `:2:2` displays the number to 2 decimal places correctly as it's in a `WriteLn` statement. This part of the program compiles and runs without any issues.
The problem is the second part of the code, `rate := J.FindPath('rates.PLN').AsFloat:2:2;` isn't a valid way to pass the amount to the variable `rate`.

Comment: I'm just being dense... you're referring to the `:2:2` that's in the line `rate := J.FindPath('rates.PLN').AsFloat:2:2;` taking that out fixes the problem thankyou.